# Does the syntax changed for class extensions?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, class-extensions

I had code like below:

```
@interface InterfaceWithACategory () {
    ... Some variables
}
@end
```

Which worked perfect when compiled in XCode 4.0.2

Now I did an upgrade (already blame myself for this stupid idea) to XCode 4.2 + iOS SDK 5.0 and have an error "Expected identifier or '(' before '{' token".

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: maybe a stupid suggestion, but have you tried without the () ?

Comment: then it would be a redefinition of the same interface, this one is a class-extension.

Comment: then you should put a name inside brackets like: @interface InterfaceWithACategory (CategoryName) even if it's not really used

Comment: Categories without a name inside () are perfectly acceptabale.  It sounds like your frameworks got messed up in the project file.  I recommend removing all frameworks from the build phase and project, then re-adding them all, 1 by 1.  If that doesnt fix it, please show the exact error message your getting.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it should be valid, and I'd hope that 5 hasn't broken that.  (You can, BTW, install 5 without overwriting 4, if you do it right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can't create iVars on a class extension, you can however set declared properties using the @property syntax.

```
@interface InterfaceWithACategory ()
@property (retain) NSArray *inDisArray;
@property (retain) NSInteger iThinkYouGetInt;
@end
```

**However** in ObjC 2.1 you can do this, but set your compiler to **Apple LLVM 3.0** I tested this on Xcode 4.2 + iOS5.0 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Categories do not permit you to add instance variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html)

Comment: A class extension is not a category. It just looks like one, but it doesn't have anything in the parens ()